# Claim on divisibility of a power sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

Let $x,y,z$ are integer and $x,y>0$

Define $S(x,y)=1^y+2^y+3^y+...+x^y$

> Can it be shown that
>
> If given $z\ne0$ then  $S(x,y)\equiv z\pmod{x}$ have finitely many solution of $x$ with respect to $y$.

Example

Let $z=\pm1$ and $y\equiv 1\pmod2$ then $x=1,2$

Comment: "...have finitely many solution of $x$ with respect to $y$." What does this mean?

Comment: @Wojowu $y$ and $z$ given then there are finitely many $x$ satisfy $S(x,y)\equiv z\pmod{x}$.

Comment: This is Faulhaber’s Formula which include Bernouli numbers such  that  are congruent ot Z and fermat little theorem w'd be work here as well

Answer (score 2):

From [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) we can see that $S(x,y)*(y+1)*lcm _{2i\leq y} den (B_{2i})$ is divisible by $x$, so for $x>z*(y+1)*lcm _{2i\leq y} den (B_{2i})$ our expression $S(x,y)$ gives remainder more than $z$ modulo $x$ provided $z\not =0$.